# Finding the longest overlapping period

Tags: c#, algorithm, datetime, intervals

I have a list of records containing Id, DateFrom, DateTo. For the sake of this question we can use this one:

```
    List<(int, DateTime, DateTime)> data = new List<(int, DateTime, DateTime)>
        {
            (1, new DateTime(2012, 5, 16), new DateTime(2018, 1, 25)),
            (2, new DateTime(2009, 1, 1), new DateTime(2011, 4, 27)),
            (3, new DateTime(2014, 1, 1), new DateTime(2016, 4, 27)),
            (4, new DateTime(2015, 1, 1), new DateTime(2015, 1, 3)),
            (2, new DateTime(2013, 5, 10), new DateTime(2017, 4, 27)),
            (5, new DateTime(2013, 5, 16), new DateTime(2018, 1, 24)),
            (2, new DateTime(2017, 4, 28), new DateTime(2018, 1, 24)),
        };
```

In my real case the List could be a lot bigger. Initially I was working with the assumption that there can be only one record for a certain `Id` and I was able to come up with a pretty good solution but now, as you can see, the assumption is that you can have several periods for an `Id` and all periods should be taken into consideration when comparing the whole time.

The task is to find the two records that has the longest time overlap and to return the ids and the number of days overlapped.

Which in this sample case means that these should be records 1 and 2.

My implementation of this is the following:

```
    public (int, int, int) GetLongestElapsedPeriodWithDuplications(List<(int, DateTime, DateTime)> periods)
    {
        Dictionary<int, List<(DateTime, DateTime)>> periodsByPeriodId = new Dictionary<int, List<(DateTime, DateTime)>>();

        foreach (var period in periods)
        {
            if (periodsByPeriodId.ContainsKey(period.Item1))
            {
                periodsByPeriodId[period.Item1].Add((period.Item2, period.Item3));
            }
            else
            {
                periodsByPeriodId[period.Item1] = new List<(DateTime, DateTime)>();
                periodsByPeriodId[period.Item1].Add((period.Item2, period.Item3));
            }
        }

        int firstId = -1;
        int secondId = -1;
        int periodInDays = 0;

        foreach (var period in periodsByPeriodId)
        {
            var Id = period.Key;

            foreach (var currPeriod in periodsByPeriodId)
            {
                int currentPeriodInDays = 0;
                if (Id != currPeriod.Key)
                {
                    for (var i = 0; i < period.Value.Count; i++)
                    {
                        for (var j = 0; j < currPeriod.Value.Count; j++)
                        {
                            var firstPeriodDateFrom = period.Value[i].Item1;
                            var firstPeriodDateTo = period.Value[i].Item2;

                            var secondPeriodDateFrom = currPeriod.Value[j].Item1;
                            var secondPeriodDateTo = currPeriod.Value[j].Item2;

                            if (secondPeriodDateFrom < firstPeriodDateTo && secondPeriodDateTo > firstPeriodDateFrom)
                            {
                                DateTime commonStartingDate = secondPeriodDateFrom > firstPeriodDateFrom ? secondPeriodDateFrom : firstPeriodDateFrom;
                                DateTime commonEndDate = secondPeriodDateTo > firstPeriodDateTo ? firstPeriodDateTo : secondPeriodDateTo;

                                currentPeriodInDays += (int)(commonEndDate - commonStartingDate).TotalDays;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (currentPeriodInDays > periodInDays)
                    {
                        periodInDays = currentPeriodInDays;
                        firstId = Id;
                        secondId = currPeriod.Key;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return (firstId, secondId, periodInDays);
    }
```

As you can see the method is pretty big and in my opinion far from optimized in terms of execution speed. I know that those nested loops rise the complexity a lot, but this additional requirement to deal with more than one period for an `Id` really left me without ideas. How can I optimize this logic so in case of bigger input it would execute faster than now?

Comment: I'm not very sure that I understand properly, so I have question: if you combine all periods for the same ID - is it possible to consider it as single interval or there could be holes?

Comment: @IlyaBursov Actually most certainly if there is more than one period for an id then there will be hole. The `List` with data is just for testing purposes in case you want to copy-paste the method and execute it with some sample data set, since at least I hope, this one is working, no matter how ugly the method is.

Comment: Is it possible to have two overlapping periods for the same ID?

Comment: No, the periods are in linear time. No overlapping for the same id.

Comment: The same question in https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/186014/finding-the-longest-overlapping-period/186031?noredirect=1#comment354707_186031 much easier to read using `for` loops instead of `for each`

Comment: @AJD Hi, and it's not the same question. This one has more than one record for the same ID, so I think it's a lot different. Also you can not use index with `Dictionary` please, if you think you can provide better solution write the code and submit it as an answer. I'll be more than happy to accept it if it really works.

Comment: Leron - you have somehow managed to complicate your reasonable and simple algorithm - You can solve your problem with 2 simple `for` loops. Instead, you have now inserted two `for each` loops with two `for` loops - and the `for` loops are not optimised as I suggested in the other post.

Comment: @Leron You ask for optimization, but can you give an idea of the scope / scale of the actual data? What is the average # of spans per ID? What is the time distribution of spans? How many IDs and spans are there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in your original solution - you need to compare each interval with any other, *except* intervals with the same id, so I'd code this like this:

Supporting classes, just to simplify actual algorithm:

```
class Period {
    public DateTime Start { get; }
    public DateTime End { get; }

    public Period(DateTime start, DateTime end) {
        this.Start = start;
        this.End = end;
    }

    public int Overlap(Period other) {
        DateTime a = this.Start > other.Start ? this.Start : other.Start;
        DateTime b = this.End < other.End ? this.End : other.End;
        return (a < b) ? b.Subtract(a).Days : 0;
    }
}

class IdData {
    public IdData() {
        this.Periods = new List<Period>();
        this.Overlaps = new Dictionary<int, int>();
    }
    public List<Period> Periods { get; }
    public Dictionary<int, int> Overlaps { get; }
}
```

Method to find max overlap:

```
    static int GetLongestElapsedPeriod(List<(int, DateTime, DateTime)> periods) {
        int maxOverlap = 0;

        Dictionary<int, IdData> ids = new Dictionary<int, IdData>();
        foreach (var period in periods) {
            int id = period.Item1;
            Period idPeriod = new Period(period.Item2, period.Item3);

            // preserve interval for ID
            var idData = ids.GetValueOrDefault(id, new IdData());
            idData.Periods.Add(idPeriod);
            ids[id] = idData;

            foreach (var idObj in ids) {
                if (idObj.Key != id) {
                    // here we calculate of new interval with all previously met
                    int o = idObj.Value.Overlaps.GetValueOrDefault(id, 0);
                    foreach (var otherPeriods in idObj.Value.Periods)
                        o += idPeriod.Overlap(otherPeriods);
                    idObj.Value.Overlaps[id] = o;

                    // check whether newly calculate overlapping is the maximal one, preserve Ids if needed too
                    if (o > maxOverlap)
                        maxOverlap = o;
                }
            }
        }

        return maxOverlap;
    }
```

Comment: This solution is closer to the way I implemented mine, but I wonder, will it perform better in terms of execution time? There are stil a lot of loops, from where we expect to have the performance boost?

Comment: @Leron this solution is O(N^2), it is the same as solution for the problem with unique ID, but constant and memory consumption is bigger

Comment: I'm not too much into algorithms (as you can see) so can you explain how it's O(N^2)? We have `foreach (var period in periods)` then `foreach (var idObj in ids)` and inside it one more loop `foreach (var otherPeriods in idObj.Value.Periods)`. From what I know, generally two nested loops make the complexity O(N^2) what happens with the thrid one?

Comment: @Leron two internal loops are basically re-formulation of `foreach period in periods before current one`, this is why it is still N^2

Comment: I find your answer easiest to understand and implement so I will accept it. Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: @IlyaBursov Your answer doesn't return the two IDs originally requested?

Comment: @NetMage no, but its very easy to change, check the comments in code

Answer (score 1):

With an extension method:

```
public static T MaxBy<T, TKey>(this IEnumerable<T> src, Func<T, TKey> key, Comparer<TKey> keyComparer = null) {
    keyComparer = keyComparer ?? Comparer<TKey>.Default;
    return src.Aggregate((a, b) => keyComparer.Compare(key(a), key(b)) > 0 ? a : b);
}
```

And some helper functions

```
DateTime Max(DateTime a, DateTime b) => (a > b) ? a : b;
DateTime Min(DateTime a, DateTime b) => (a < b) ? a : b;

int OverlappingDays((DateTime DateFrom, DateTime DateTo) span1, (DateTime DateFrom, DateTime DateTo) span2) {
    var maxFrom = Max(span1.DateFrom, span2.DateFrom);
    var minTo = Min(span1.DateTo, span2.DateTo);
    return Math.Max((minTo - maxFrom).Days, 0);
}
```

You can group together the spans with matching `Id`s

```
var dg = data.GroupBy(d => d.Id);
```

Generate all pairs of `Id`s

```
var pdgs = from d1 in dg
           from d2 in dg.Where(d => d.Key > d1.Key)
           select new[] { d1, d2 };
```

Then compute the overlap in days between each pair of `Id`s and find the maximum:

```
var MaxOverlappingPair = pdgs.Select(pdg => new {
    Id1 = pdg[0].Key,
    Id2 = pdg[1].Key,
    OverlapInDays = pdg[0].SelectMany(d1 => pdg[1].Select(d2 => OverlappingDays((d1.DateFrom, d1.DateTo), (d2.DateFrom, d2.DateTo)))).Sum()
}).MaxBy(TwoOverlap => TwoOverlap.OverlapInDays);
```

Since efficiency is mentioned, I should say that implementing some of these operations directly instead of using LINQ is more efficient, but you are using Tuples and in-memory structures so I don't think it will make much difference.

I ran some performance tests using a list of 24000 spans with 1249 unique IDs. The LINQ code took about 16 seconds. By inlining some of the LINQ and replacing anonymous objects with tuples, it came down to about 3.1 seconds. By adding a shortcut skipping any IDs whose cumulative days were shorter than the current max overlapping days and a few more optimizations, I got it down to less than 1 second.

```
var baseDate = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);

int OverlappingDays(int DaysFrom1, int DaysTo1, int DaysFrom2, int DaysTo2) {
    var maxFrom = DaysFrom1 > DaysFrom2 ? DaysFrom1 : DaysFrom2;
    var minTo = DaysTo1 < DaysTo2 ? DaysTo1 : DaysTo2;
    return (minTo > maxFrom) ? minTo - maxFrom : 0;
}

var dgs = data.Select(d => {
    var DaysFrom = (d.DateFrom - baseDate).Days;
    var DaysTo = (d.DateTo - baseDate).Days;
    return (d.Id, DaysFrom, DaysTo, Dist: DaysTo - DaysFrom);
})
              .GroupBy(d => d.Id)
              .Select(dg => (Id: dg.Key, Group: dg, Dist: dg.Sum(d => d.Dist)))
              .ToList();

var MaxOverlappingPair = (Id1: 0, Id2: 0, OverlapInDays: 0);

for (int j1 = 0; j1 < dgs.Count; ++j1) {
    var dg1 = dgs[j1];
    if (dg1.Dist > MaxOverlappingPair.OverlapInDays)
        for (int j2 = j1 + 1; j2 < dgs.Count; ++j2) {
            var dg2 = dgs[j2];
            if (dg2.Dist > MaxOverlappingPair.OverlapInDays) {
                var testOverlapInDays = 0;
                foreach (var d1 in dg1.Group)
                    foreach (var d2 in dg2.Group)
                        testOverlapInDays += OverlappingDays(d1.DaysFrom, d1.DaysTo, d2.DaysFrom, d2.DaysTo);

                if (testOverlapInDays > MaxOverlappingPair.OverlapInDays)
                    MaxOverlappingPair = (dg1.Id, dg2.Id, testOverlapInDays);
            }
        }
}
```

Optimizations applied:

1. Convert each spans `DateTime`s to # of days from an [arbitrary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) `baseDate` to optimize overlapping days calculation by doing date conversion once.
2. Compute the total days for each span and skip any span pairs that can't exceed the current overlap
3. Replace `SelectMany`/`Select` with nested `foreach` to compute overlapping days.
4. Use `ValueTuple`s instead of anonymous objects which are (slightly) faster for this problem.
5. Replace pair generation LINQ with nested `for` loops generating each possible pair directly
6. Pass individual from/to parameters instead of objects to `OverlappingDays` function

Note: I tried a smarter overlapping days calculation but when the number of spans per ID is small, the overhead took longer than just doing the calculation directly.

Comment: This is pretty neat way to solve the problem, however I wonder if the performance will be better. You have `Select` inside `SelectMany` isn't that like nesting loops?

Comment: @Leron Yes, it is. It turns out that there is a large performance hit there. Replacing the expression with two nested `foreach` loops saves about 55% of the time. Replacing the `SelectMany` with `Select` by `Sum`ing inside claws back 20%.

Comment: To be honest I quite like the LINQ solution, but the performance impact is too great. But the test you've done is pretty interesting, I really wondered if the compiler is able to optimize the LINQ query so that it performs better. Obviously not.

Comment: @Leron In general, LINQ is easier to write, but slower to run - sometimes much slower. Just out of curiousity, I ran `GetLongestElapsedPeriod` against my 20k list and it isn't bad, about 7.7 seconds, about 36% faster than LINQ. I am working on something that may be much faster, I will have to see.

Comment: Wow, 7.7 seconds, not bad at all! I'm really interested in what are you working on. Please share your idea/code if/when possible!

Comment: @Leron That was the function from your accepted answer - my code was doing it in 3.1 seconds. I have it running in 1 second now with my last optimization.

Comment: What would be the `baseDate` used here -> `var dgs = data.Select(d => (d.Id, DaysFrom: (d.DateFrom - baseDate).Days,` ?

Comment: Sorry, it is arbitrary. I updated my answer with the value used, and further optimizations I thought of over the weekend. I am know running tests at 160000 spans and 8000 IDs to get reasonable repeatibility.

Comment: Hi, it would be easier to talk here: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164130/longestelapsedperiod

Answer (score 1):

You can use **TimePeriodLibrary.NET**:

> PM> Install-Package TimePeriodLibrary.NET

```
TimePeriodCollection timePeriods = new TimePeriodCollection(
    data.Select(q => new TimeRange(q.Item2, q.Item3)));

var longestOverlap = timePeriods
    .OverlapPeriods(new TimeRange(timePeriods.Start, timePeriods.End))
    .OrderByDescending(q => q.Duration)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: I don't know if it works, but this is my favorite answer. Excellent use of the available tools.

Comment: @koryakinp I didn't know this library. Thanks for sharing it. However for this problem I don't want to use external libs. Still, really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

There are already few solutions

but

if you want to improve the efficiency then you don't have to compare every objects/value with everyother value or object. You can use `Interval Search Tree` for this problem and it can be solved in `RlogN`  where `R` are number of intersections between intervals.

I recommend you to watch this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3kpmHEJXrsA&t=1s) of Robert Sedgwick and also that book is online available.

Answer (score -2):

Your basic problem here is how to identify a unique set of time periods. Give each one its own unique ID yourself.

When you write your final answer, include the additional details in the output so the user can understand which (original) IDs and original time periods resulted in the final answer.

Remember - the problem is still the same as in the original post (https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/186014/finding-the-longest-overlapping-period/186031?noredirect=1#comment354707_186031) and you still have the same information to work with. Don't get too hung up on the "ID"s as provided in the original list - you are still iterating through a list of time periods.

Comment: I'm not sure if I can't understand your idea, or you underestimate the problem. In both cases - if you think you have an answer to my question just write a code, not an essay and as I said I will be more than happy to accept it if it really performs better. As of now, I really appreciate your suggestions for refactoring from the posted question, that's why I accepted it and I'll apply them to the first algorithm. This one, at least in my opinion is different and untill you provide a working code this is my opinion.

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. And, as noted in the other post - I am not a C# programmer, so I cannot write valid C# code, all I can do is give you a valid algorithm.

Comment: @Leron - I am trying to give you pointers so that you understand your own problem and understand your own code.

Comment: You had a working algorithm in the other post - you have totally screwed it this time. Your other algorithm will still work for this latest problem (you noted that for each individual ID, the timeperiods do not overlap).

Comment: @AJD I don't think you understand the new problem. You must take into account the __sum__ of the overlaps of all the periods assigned to a pair of IDs.

Comment: I'll point out that while in theory SO is not a code writing service, in practice, it is.

Comment: @NetMage - Ok, I missed that detail on my read through (bearing in mind I had only just finished optimising the first version).